# Calculating probabilities of ball landing on a column in a wheel

Tags: probability

On a roulette wheel, to calculate the probability of consecutive red and black numbers, I just do $(18/37)^n$

This works fine when talking about red and black numbers or even and odd numbers, because we only have 2 factors.

I am wondering how can I do the same calculation but with columns, 3 factors.

So if I have column 1 (numbers from 1 to 12), column 2(numbers of 13 to 24) and column 3 (numbers from 25 to 36) how do I calculate the probability of the ball landing on column 1, knowing how many times the ball has already landed on column 2 and 3 in 100 spins on a total of 200?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, knowing the ball has already landed on column $2$ and $3$ in $100$ on a total of $200$ does not tell you anything about the next spin, unless you suspect that the game is not fair.  The probabilities are already determined in advance, and the fact that an unlikely scenario has occurred previously does not make any other scenario and more or less likely to occur.

I'm not $100\%$ sure I know what quantity you're looking for.  Are you asking, "what's the probability of getting the first column $n$ times out of $100$ rolls?"  In that case, since there's a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of getting in the first column and a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of landing in either $2$ or $3$, then the probability is $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{100-n}$

Comment: Well, the $\frac13$ is in fact $\frac{12}{37}$  for the sake of the bank

Comment: Of course my question was not well presented. Assume that the ball has never landed on the 1st column in 100 spins ( improbable and this is what I am trying to understand ), how do I calculate the probability of the ball landing on the 1st column? With red and black numbers the probability increases to land on the opposite color on every spin, but in this case, how do I calculate that?

Comment: I think you and I are disagreeing on the red/black case as well. In particular, I disagree with this: "With red and black numbers the probability increases to land on the opposite color on every spin, but in this case, how do I calculate that? "  It sounds a lot like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_carlo_fallacy

Comment: @DiegoPucci - the odds of heads (for a coin) are 50/50 regardless of the prior N flips. After some number, you might convince yourself the coin isn't fair, but if the given is that it's a fair coin, it's 50/50 to infinity.